# on OSX mongo fails to start

Tags: mongodb

I am writing mongo in shell. but it is not starting. The error message is:

```
W NETWORK [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `mongod` Before `mongo`. May be You forgot to do that.

Comment: Welcome. Don't forget to put a tick mark if it helps :)